# Not able to click element using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, webdriver

I am having this screen where i try to hover it
[image]

after hovering the screen becomes drop down

[image]

So i am not able to click on the screen using selenium webdriver.

```
<td align="left" style="vertical-align: top;">
<div id="gwt-debug-ddPolicy" class="relativePositionNegative12">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="clickable GP432FWBBU">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td align="left" style="vertical-align: top;">
     <div class="GP432FWBOT GP432FWBDU GP432FWBAU GP432FWBDD" aria-hidden="false" id="gwt-debug-ddPolicy-label" style="">linda</div>
    </td>
   <td align="left" style="vertical-align: top;">
        <select class="GP432FWBOT GP432FWBMT GP432FWBAU" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true" id="ddPolicy">
           <option value="linda">linda</option>
           <option value="Gaurav">Gaurav</option>
           <option value="*Aung">*Aung</option>
           <option value="Aakash">Aakash</option>
        </select>
    </td>
   <td align="left" style="vertical-align: top;">
   </td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</td>
```

I am getting error for other element get position.

Comment: share your code and error message.

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (880, 219). Other element would receive the click: <div class="GP432FWBFT"></div>
  (Session info: chrome=51.0.2704.103)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.22.397933

Comment: I won´t post this as an answer since it's a pretty dirty solution but it seems that the "aria-hidden" attribute controls if the select is shown or not, so you could go with 'JavascriptExecutor JSE =(JavascriptExecutor) driver;
JSE.executeScript("document.getElementsByClassName('GP432FWBOT GP432FWBMT GP432FWBAU'[0].setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'false')");' This way, if I got the HTML right, it should show the select box and you can let the WebDriver look for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't found a way to do a 'mouse over' option but you can use Action Chains to achieve this.

```
Actions action = new Actions(webdriver);
WebElement we = webdriver.findElement(By.xpath("expression"));
action.moveToElement(we).moveToElement(webdriver.findElement(By.xpath("expression"))).click().build().perform();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try sending an empty key to the element in order to focus on it as well as set get visible over hidden property.  For example:

```
hidden_element.send_keys "" // This will make element visible first.
hidden_element.click() // Pretty simple job when element is visible.
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your question use `ExplicitWait` command, this is useful in finding the elements until it gets enables in webpages. It will wait until you get desired element in webpage as:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(By.xpath("xpath expression")
```

You can find real time examples in this [website](http://www.wikishown.com/selenium-tutorials).

Answer (score 0):

```
        webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div#gwt-debug-ddPolicy")).click();

        JavascriptExecutor executor= (JavascriptExecutor)webDriver;
        executor.executeScript("document.getElementById('ddPolicy').style.display='block';");
        Select select1 = new Select(webDriver.findElement(By.id("ddPolicy")));
        select1.selectByVisibleText("Gaurav");
```

Code worked for me.